# Multiplos LEFT JOIN e busca lenta

Tags: mysql

Numa aplicação de um cliente (um calendário escolar e registo de faltas/presenças) existe esta query:

```
SELECT *, the_courses.course_desc as course_name, schedule.id as schedule_id, students.id as student_id, attendance.id_state as presence, attendance.id as presence_id
FROM ".T_BOOKINGS." AS attendance
LEFT JOIN ".T_BOOKINGS_CLIENT_BOOKINGS." AS schedule ON attendance.id_client_booking = schedule.id
LEFT JOIN ".T_STUDENT_SUBJECT_MATRIX." AS subject_matrix ON schedule.classes_id=subject_matrix.class
LEFT JOIN ".T_SCHOOL_COURSE." AS the_courses ON schedule.course_id = the_courses.id     
LEFT JOIN ".T_BOOKINGS_CLIENTS." AS students ON subject_matrix.student = students.id
LEFT JOIN ".T_CLASS_DETAILS." AS classes ON schedule.classes_id= classes.id 
    AND attendance.student_id= students.id 
WHERE classes.state<>0 ".$sql_condition." ORDER BY schedule.the_date DESC";
```

A query demora mais de 1 minuto a responder e eu pergunto-me se há uma maneira mais efeciente de fazer esta query no MySql.

`T_BOOKINGS_CLIENT_BOOKINGS` regista os horários das lições, ~3.500 registos (InnoDB)
`T_BOOKINGS` registo de faltas. Uma entrada cada aula/aluno/dia, ~24.000 registos (MyISAM)
`T_STUDENT_SUBJECT_MATRIX` regista aulas que cada aluno está inscrito. ~450 registos (InnoDB)
`$sql_condition` é um filtro para mostrar aluno, aula ou professor específicos, consoante selects no front-end.

As outras tabelas são registo de alunos e salas de aula para o MySql ir buscar nomes para completar no HTML que o ajax retorna. Todas as tabelas têm index PRIMARY/BTREE/unico na coluna id da tabela que são `int(11)`.

EXPLAIN:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes correr um [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) e adicionar o _screenshot_? Ajuda a avaliar o problema.

Comment: @Zuul juntei o explain.

Comment: Este `AND attendance.student_id= students.id ` não deveria estar após o `WHERE` ? Onde está entra no ultimo `LEFT JOIN mas não trabalha sobre o mesmo o que gera uma verificação extra a todos os registos.

Comment: Outra coisa a ter em atenção, na primeira linha do `EXPLAIN`: O [`Using temporary`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information) indica que foi preciso criar uma tabela temporária para resolver a consulta. Isto é lento e pode ser a grande causa por trás desse teu tempo de espera. Repara que nessa mesma linha não foi escolhido nenhum index para resolver a consulta.

Comment: Para uma base com uns poucos milhares de registros como a sua essa demora é estranha. Se você está retornando muitos registros um índice pela coluna date, pela qual está sendo feita a ordenação pode ajudar. Além disso verifique se vc pode trocar algum outter join por um inner join.

Comment: Com `*` já posso te adiantar que pode ser isso. Digo isso pois passei pelo mesmo problema, mas a tabela tinha váaaarias colunas. Talvez no seu caso não mude nada selecionar explicitamente as colunas.

Comment: Você precisa realmente de LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Explicação da consulta

Sempre que uma consulta está demorada, corre um [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) pois o mesmo dá-te informação crucial para entenderes o que pode estar errado.

No teu caso, o [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) salienta na coluna [`Extra`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information) que na consulta no que respeita à tabela `subject_matrix` não está a encontrar nenhuma indexação para construir o resultado, estando assim a criar uma tabela temporária para guardar os resultados de forma a conseguir resolver a consulta solicitada.

As causas tem diversas origens, mas geralmente existe um campo chave usado para fazer ligação com outras tabelas ou sobre o qual é realizada a pesquisa cujo mesmo não se encontra indexado, obrigando o MySQL a correr todos os registos por cada vez que vai à tabela em questão.

No teu caso em particular, o campo `subject_matrix.class` parece ser o responsável, pelo que deverás verificar se o mesmo está indexado.

> **Boa prática:**
>   Ver sempre o resultado do `EXPLAIN`. Alguns problemas só os "vemos" quando as aplicações crescem, mas um `EXPLAIN` da consulta ajuda-nos a prever potenciais dores de cabeça!

---

## Ordenação dos resultados

Em consultas complexas, a ordenação apresenta um impacto na performance da consulta à base de dados.

No teu caso, dada a quantidade de `JOIN`, o campo utilizado para ordenação deve estar indexado pela forma como pretendes receber os resultados.

O campo `the_date` da tabela `schedule` deve estar indexado de forma `DESC`.

> **Boa prática:**
>   Ter sempre a coluna de ordenação indexada, não se perde nada.

---

## Condições da consulta

As colunas sobre as quais vamos verificar dados para obtermos resultados numa consulta devem estar indexadas.

Sempre que o MySQL vai verificar se existe um registo com o valor `X` na coluna `Y`, ele vai ter que ir linha a linha verificar e comparar o valor da coluna `Y` com o valor `X` recebido.

Se existir indexação na coluna `Y`, o MySQL vai realizar a consulta sobre o *index* da mesma, evitando assim percorrer toda a tabela para verificar se tem resultados.

```php
$sql_condition
```

Esta variável contém condições, condições essas que trabalham sobre determinadas colunas de determinadas tabelas. As colunas em questão devem estar indexadas para tornar o trabalho de pesquisa sobre as mesmas mais eficaz.

Este cenário pode agravar-se ainda mais quando existem `JOIN` e a condição obriga a verificar cada registo da tabela principal com cada registo da tabela secundária.

```sql
JOIN tabela ON ( campo = campo )
```

As colunas sobre as quais estabelecemos uma relação entre tabelas devem de igual forma permitir uma comparação indexada, dando preferência sempre que possível a relações por chaves numéricas.

> **Boa prática:**
>   Se a coluna vai ser alvo de pesquisa, indexar.

---

## Sintaxe e Indentação

Em termos gerais, a sintaxe e indentação são nossos amigos pois ajudam-nos a ler de forma mais eficaz e ajudam-nos também a identificar pequenos detalhes ou gralhas que podem ser os causadores do problema em mãos.

Uma das coisas que recomendo aos iniciados em MySQL é o uso dos parênteses. Os mesmos acabam por ser descartados pelo MySQL na maior parte dos casos, mas noutros ajudam-nos a aperceber-nos de potenciais problemas.

No teu caso, uma linha fora do local é causadora de algum redundância no apuramento dos resultados:

```sql
-- ...
AND attendance.student_id = students.id
-- ...
```

Está a ser apanhada pelo `JOIN` errado. Ao adicionarmos sintaxe e indentação fica:

```sql
-- ...
LEFT JOIN ".T_CLASS_DETAILS." AS classes ON (
    schedule.classes_id = classes.id
    AND
    attendance.student_id = students.id
)
-- ...
```

Mas na realidade, dado ambos os campos não dizerem respeito ao alias `classes`, o pretendido presume-se ser:

```sql
-- ...
LEFT JOIN ".T_BOOKINGS_CLIENTS." AS students ON (
    subject_matrix.student = students.id
    AND
    attendance.student_id = students.id
)
LEFT JOIN ".T_CLASS_DETAILS." AS classes ON (
    schedule.classes_id= classes.id
)
-- ...
```

Com vista a prevenir potenciais problemas originados pelo em cima referido, eu sugiro a tua consulta indentada da seguinte forma:

```php
$query = "
SELECT
    the_courses.course_desc AS course_name,
    schedule.id AS schedule_id,
    students.id AS student_id,
    attendance.id_state AS presence,
    attendance.id AS presence_id
FROM ".T_BOOKINGS." AS attendance
LEFT JOIN ".T_BOOKINGS_CLIENT_BOOKINGS." AS schedule ON (
    attendance.id_client_booking = schedule.id
)
LEFT JOIN ".T_STUDENT_SUBJECT_MATRIX." AS subject_matrix ON (
    schedule.classes_id = subject_matrix.class
)
LEFT JOIN ".T_SCHOOL_COURSE." AS the_courses ON (
    schedule.course_id = the_courses.id
)
LEFT JOIN ".T_BOOKINGS_CLIENTS." AS students ON (
    subject_matrix.student = students.id
    AND
    attendance.student_id = students.id
)
LEFT JOIN ".T_CLASS_DETAILS." AS classes ON (
    schedule.classes_id = classes.id
)
WHERE classes.state<>0
".$sql_condition."
ORDER BY schedule.the_date DESC ";
```

> **Boa prática:**
>   Mesmo estando a trabalhar num ficheiro que diz respeito a outra linguagem de programação, no teu caso parece-me ser PHP, o código MySQL deve estar indentado e com a sintaxe devidamente destacada para facilitar a leitura e manutenção futura.

---

## Campos a recolher

Repara que em cima ao indentar a consulta retirei o `*` da lista de campos a recolher.

Quando realizamos uma consulta sobre uma única tabela, dizer ao MySQL que queremos tudo não tem impacto na performance:

```
SELECT * FROM superBuBu
```

Mas quando estamos a trabalhar com consultas onde juntamos várias tabelas, temos que ter em conta que o `*` vai dizer ao MySQL: *Eu quero todos os campos de todas as tabelas*.

> **Boa prática:**
>   
>   Em termos práticos, se por algum motivo o MySQL tiver que processar os dados duma forma mais extensa, vai ter muito menos informação com que se preocupar o que o levará a ser mais rápido.

---

### Referente ao teu caso em particular:

Após as explicações em cima dadas, é possível concluir que as mesmas justificam os teus problemas de performance na tua consulta.

Se sintetizarmos os esforços extra que o MySQL está a ter com a consulta:

- Vimos que o MySQL está a criar uma tabela temporária para poder guardar os resultados da consulta enquanto os trabalha;
- Vimos que o MySQL está a percorrer os resultados da consulta linha a linha para discernir se cada uma das linhas deve ser incluída nos resultados;
- Vimos que após tudo isto os resultados ainda tem que ser ordenados por um campo de forma descendente;
- E vimos que estamos a dizer ao MySQL para selecionar todas as colunas de todas as tabelas envolvidas, o que resulta numa MEGA tabela temporária.

concluímos que se não todo o problema, pelo menos a maior fatia do mesmo fica  resolvida se esses pontos foram tratados como sugerido.

---

<sup>**Nota:**

A resposta é capaz de ter ficado um pouco densa, mas a ideia foi transmitir de forma pouco técnica alguns dos cuidados a ter para realizar consultas em MySQL com foco nos problemas mais comuns tomando como exemplo prático o problema do @Sergio.</sup>

<sup>A resposta do [@utluiz♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37887/223) já falava sobre estes problemas, mas achei relevante deixar uma explicação mais detalhada para o menos iniciado.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Juntando alguns comentários (@Zull, @jean e @Earendul) com mais algumas informações, reuni um conjunto de ações que devem ajudar a melhorar o desempenho:

1. Remova o `*` e selecione apenas os campos realmente necessários.
2. Crie um índice no campo `schedule.the_date` para a ordenação ficar mais eficiente.
3. A cláusula `AND attendance.student_id= students.id` deveria estar uma linha acima, afinal ela faz o *join* da tabela `students`.
4. Crie um índice no campo `subject_matrix.class`, pois o MySQL está fazendo um *table scan* em todos os registros para encontrar o que precisa.
5. Crie um ou mais índices envolvendo os campos `classes.state`, aluno, aula e professor. Eles são usados na sua `$sql_condition` e isso está causando outro *table scan*. Note no *explain* que milhares de registros estão sendo lidos um a um para fazer o filtro. O índice evitaria essa quantidade de leitura.

<sup>Nota: a resposta era um comentário que ficou muito grande.</sup>